# Is it true that $ |\sin^2z+\cos^2z|=1, \forall z \in\Bbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

We know that equation $ \sin^2z+ \cos^2z=1$ which holds  $ \forall z \in\Bbb R$, actually holds $ \forall z \in\Bbb C$.

Is it true that $ |\sin^2z+\cos^2z|=1, \forall z \in\Bbb C$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $|z|\in \mathbb R$, so yes.

Comment: Actually I wanted to asking something else. Previously I put modulus on wrong place. Please check edited question.

Comment: $|1| = 1$, so, yes.

Answer (score 11):

In general, if an identity holds for a smooth function over real numbers, then the same identity also holds over the complex numbers. (Amazing!)

In this case: $$\cos^2(z)+\sin^2(z)=(\cos(z)+i\sin(z))(\cos(z)-i\sin(z))=e^{iz}e^{-iz}=1$$
where you need the exponential definition of trigonometric functions. There is no need for the absolute value in your question.

Comment: While there is some truth to your first sentence (due to the identity theorem for holomorphic functions) it is not true as stated. I'm not even sure what "the same identity" is supposed to mean if you start with a *smooth* function defined on $\mathbb{R}$: Arguably, $|x|^2 = x^2$ is an identity for a "smooth function over real numbers", but the "same identity", $|z|^2 = z^2$ doesn't hold for $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start

$$ \sin z = \sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cos(iy)+\sin(iy)\cos(x),\quad i=\sqrt{-1}. $$

> $$ \implies \sin z = \sin(x) \cosh(y)+i\sinh(y)\cos(x). $$

Now, do the same with $\cos z$ and substitute back in your equation

> $$ |\sin^2 z +\cos^2 z | $$

and see what you get.

**Added:** If you work the problem further, then we have

$$ \sin^2 z +\cos^2 z $$

$$=  \sin^2  x   \cosh^2 y
 - \cos^2 x  \sinh^2  y +  \cos^2  x \cosh^2 y -
 \sin^2 x \sinh^2 y =1. $$

**Note:**

> $$\cosh^2 t - \sinh^2 t =1. $$

Comment: It gave us some weird result. $|cosh^2y-sinh^2+2isinx.sinhy.coshy(siny+cosx)|$.
It doesn't give us any clue. What do you think now? Are we heading in right direction?

Comment: @SaraTancredi: You are not done yet. You need to evaluate the modulus and make further simplifications.

Comment: Oh i see. So should it be 1 in the end? Or you don't know about the final answer?

Comment: @SaraTancredi: I added more material.

Comment: @SaraTancredi: Note that, when you simplify $\sin^2 z +\cos^2 z$ you end up with one and its modulus is one. Work the problem step by step to see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you so much Mhenni. Let me do it.

Comment: @SaraTancredi: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

When you take the Absolute Value of $z$ you get a number in $\mathbb R$, and since $\left|z\right|\in \mathbb R$, $\sin^2|z|+\cos^2|z|=1$, so the answer is yes

Comment: I am really sorry. My question was different. I did mistake while writing the question. Please check it now. Thanks